# gcc warning different when using --preprocessed

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, warnings

When compiling ltrace with icecc we run into a compilation problem. This is the minimal example:

main.c

```
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    assert(argc != argc);
    return 0;
}
```

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

# one step compilation (no warning)
gcc -Wall main.c

# splitted compilation (warning)
gcc -Wall -E main.c -o main.i
gcc -Wall --preprocessed main.i
```

output:

```
++ gcc -Wall main.c
++ gcc -Wall -E main.c -o main.i
++ gcc -Wall --preprocessed main.i
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4:10: warning: self-comparison always evaluates to false [-Wtautological-compare]
      assert(argc != argc);
          ^~
```

As you can see the result is different when compiling in one step and when preprocessing and compiling in two steps. Is this intended behavior?

I use gcc 6.3, the issue also appears in gcc 6.2 for ARM. I also cannot ignore this, as the full example uses -Werror.